# Which url needs to be invalidate for clearing volley cache?

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

Actually I have a small confusion regarding volley cache management. Suppose I have an API with BASE URL `http://example.com` but when I am calling my api I am appending one layout params so finally it looks like `http://example.com?sort_by=distance`.

So if I want to clear the cache for this url which one should my key
`http://example.com` or `http://example.com?sort_by=distance`

And if answer is second one then do I need to clear cache independently for all the url that created by different url params.

Comment: This looks to me as if you're accessing a webservice, which does not cache data...

Comment: my website let me cache url data. But sometimes when I get a update flag I need to clear my cache and call the api again.

Comment: Inside [Request.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/2afdd91aba3a7a5396fe96dfe8f930661e56ea9a/src/com/android/volley/Request.java) /**
     `* Returns the cache key for this request.  By default, this is the URL.
     */
    public String getCacheKey() {
        return getUrl();
    }` then `public Request(int method, String url, Response.ErrorListener listener) {
        mMethod = method;
        mUrl = url;
        mErrorListener = listener;
        setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy());
    }`

Answer (score 0):

volley (and i guess all other caching systems) use the exact detailed url u call as a key for cache data.
if you wanna delete a cache entry u need to do it by exact full link.
the link "www.example.com/amir?id=1" is different from "www.example.com/amir?id=2". otherwise caching would be more trouble than efficient.

Answer (score 0):

BTW you don't need to delete caches. It is something volley handles considering some factors.

If you need to call a link skipping all cache systems in client and server the easiest way is to put an timpestamp at the end of the API calls.
If your link is `www.example.com/amir/id/2` make your link like this => `www.example.com/amir/id/2?timestamp=54461`.

Generate the number in front of timestamp by `System.currentTimeMillis()` of Java. You can divide it by a number to make cache values valid for a fraction of time.